# wireless card problem rtl8192se autodisconnects after a few minutes in 13.04

Tags: wireless, 13.04, realtek

I am using wireless card rtl8192se. The official site of realtek provided a driver that supports kernel up to 3.2.x but recently i upgraded to 13.04 so i cannot use it.

Initially the driver in the kernel works find but after a while it start disconnecting after a few minutes.

The signal strength shown in the panel drops from 4/5 to 2 yet if I click open the menu, the strength remains. In the same time, network slows down drastically (from 100+kb/s to 100b/s). Only if i disconnect and reconnect will it start to work. but after a few minutes, it appears again.

This is not a new problem, but I cannot find a solution to that, especially with kernel 3.8.x

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem here... my workaround is reloading the driver...

make a .sh script with:

```
echo deloading wifi module...
sudo rmmod rtl8192se
echo reloading wifi module...
sudo modprobe rtl8192se
```