# WiFi keeps dropping out but stills says I'm connected

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and my WiFi keeps dropping out for seemingly no good reason and I have to re-boot to get reconnected. I did do some Googling and found this [diagnostic tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos).

I ran the script and  put it into this Ubuntu Paste bin:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/9757988/

Does anyone see a problem from this result and can offer a solution? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Restarting Network Manager Service**

This is pretty self explanatory workaround, I suppose. In terminal do
`sudo service network-manager restart`;
 Alternatively, try `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

**Altering module settings**

Common solution that works for many cases is altering your module ( aka driver ) settings. 
In your instance, you have rtl8723be module for RTL8723BE PCIe card ( which is under lspci in your pastebin output ). Use `modinfo rtl8723be` what parameters there are for this driver, and you should find ips, fwlps, msi.

Now, you could either alter these parameters using `modprobe`  command as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/541881/295286) , or you could permanently change settings by creating a `rtl8723be.conf` file in `/etc/modprobe.d` folder. For instane, in command line do `sudo gedit /etc/modbrobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` , enter your password, and add something like this to the file:

```
options rtl8192se fwlps=0 ips=0 swenc=1
```

Save, close, reboot.

Side notes:  1) gedit is a graphical text editor. There are plenty of command line editors. I personally prefer nano or vim. 2) I've never personally changed parameters during runtime with modprobe as in the link, so I do not know if it should or not work during runtime. 3) there is a way of viewing the module parameters during run time with `systool -v -m modnamehere` , which is part of sysfsutils package; you can install that with `sudo apt-get install sysfsutils`.

**Reinserting module**

Another common workaround is reinserting the module at runtime. For instance, with rtl8192se wifi card , my connection would drop, indicator would say I'm disconnected, and when I'd select my wifi to reconnect, it would just hang there "configuring" until the connection timed out. Reinserting the module helped 90 % of the time. I've put all commands into a script:

```
# !/bin/bash
# Description: Simple script to reload r8192e_pci module for wireless card
# refer to  https://askubuntu.com/questions/286380/wireless-card-problem-rtl8192se-autodisconnects-after-a-few-minutes-in-13-04
echo deloading wifi module...
sudo rmmod -v r8192e_pci
echo reloading wifi module...
sudo modprobe -v r8192e_pci
```

You can replace the r8192e_pci with your rtl8723be, save in a file, for instance `mod-reload.sh` , change permissions with `chmod +x mod-reload.sh` , and then execute it with `./mod-reload.sh` . See if that helps.

**Altering kernel parameters**

In addition to my dropping connection that I've experienced with rtl8192se, I've also had interesting sound glitch/stutter in every audio-producing program, from firefox to smplayer. What helped alleviate the issue somewhat was changing the kernel boot parameters. 
Namely, here's what I've changed in `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noapictimer clocksource=jiffies"
```

Again, you can edit that part in grub file with `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` command

Side note: depending on your hardware you might use different kernel parameter there. [Refer here for more explanation](https://askubuntu.com/q/52096/295286) and [here for parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt).

**Check the connections**
Often we forget that network cards are actually hardware, and sometimes fiddling with options isn't going to solve a physical problem. If you can easily access the network card "under the hood", check if the two antenna  wires that go to it are connected nice and tight, maybe try swapping wires in places.

**Upgrade to newer kernel**
Modules come with kernels, and with each new release they may get improved. Check out this article on upgrading to [kernel 3.18.2](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/01/install-upgrade-linux-kernel-3-18-2-ubuntu/).

**Get different hardware ?**

Bad hardware may be just bad, and no amount of fiddling with it will help. Look up ubuntu recommended network cards, and maybe get one of those. Personally, I went back to my good old RTL8187SE, which is actually recommended, and put aside

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

I changed the line:

```
`*options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1*`
```

into

```
*options iwlwifi 11n_disable=0*
```

not really clear to me what I did :) but it worked!