# Ubuntu 14.04 Internet keeps dropping out

Tags: 14.04, networking

I'm not sure as to what is causing it. I found this thread which could be the answer but I'm not sure how to follow it. Is anybody able to assist?

[WiFi keeps dropping out but stills says I'm connected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574211/wifi-keeps-dropping-out-but-stills-says-im-connected)

Not sure which commands I should input and I'm afraid of breaking my computer again.

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , i had the same issue a when i installed Ubuntu 14.04.

Probably it was due to network manager.

1. I just noted down my network configuration by `ip a s` command and
2. Then purged the network manager.
3. Lastly i configured my Linux box to use static ip configuration.

Here is the guideline i followed:

https://github.com/iahmad-khan/system-admin/blob/master/ubutu14%20networking

(Skip the Ethernet related settings in that guide)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I am assuming that the etho bit is the
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback etc etc however when I did sudo update-r.d networking enable it came back with update-rc.d: warning:  start runlevel arguments (none) do not match networking Default-Start values (S)
update-rc.d: warning:  stop runlevel arguments (none) do not match networking Default-Stop values (0 6)
 System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/networking do not exist.

Comment: Its ok , it will still work

Comment: It didn't work. Not sure what I did wrong. Here's a screenshot of everything I did. The top bit is part of the purge command. https://imgur.com/F2uRHv3